# ArrayList resizing

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList object for which I know the exact size. Is there any way to specify that the ArrayList should not extend its capacity?

```
List<String> list = null;
int size = getSize(); // gets the exact number of elements I want

list = new ArrayList<String> (size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    list.add("String num: " + i);
}
```

I don't want the ArrayList to re-size because that takes time which I want to avoid wasting.

Comment: You may use [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to obtain a list that is guaranteed to have constant size.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
list = new ArrayList<String> (size);
```

This will create arraylist with 'size' as initial capacity. As long as you don't add more elements than 'size' there will be no resizing.

Also please be sure that this really takes time in your application. Unless you have profiled and identified this as issue, you will not gain much by randomly optimizing the code.

Comment: does ArrayList actually take long to resize? I think it is a very fast operation and should not be bothering anyone...

Comment: It takes hell lot of time to resize actually, but it will be only visible when your list size is really big. Like 100000- 1000000 elements.

Comment: With the implementation that I know, it is true that the `ArrayList` won’t resize when you don’t exceed its current capacity. However there is noting in the specification that prohibits it from it. I would assume that it doesn’t happen in other implementations either, but we can’t be sure.

Answer (score 5):

The `ArrayList` won't resize if you don't add more elements than it has capacity for. You've created the list with the right capacity, so it should be fine.

You *could* create a list which threw an exception if you tried to exceed the original capacity, but it's not clear why that would be useful to you here.

Comment: just as additional information, you could arbitrarily resize an `ArrayList` using [`ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact size, and it will not be extended in the future, then why don't you just use String arrays.

```
String[] strArray=new String[size];
```

Comment: I'm using a different type for the ArrayList, I just didn't want to get into that now. I like the ArrayList interface better than using a simple Object array.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do to limit an `ArrayList` would be to override the [`ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) method like in the following sample:

```
public static class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    @Override
    public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
        if (minCapacity > 10) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        super.ensureCapacity(minCapacity);
    }

}
```

A small test could be done with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyArrayList<String> items = new MyArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        try {
            items.add("itm " + i);
            System.out.println("succeeded to insert " + i);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("not able to insert " + i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("items are: " + items);
}
```

This will print:

```
succeeded to insert 0
succeeded to insert 1
succeeded to insert 2
succeeded to insert 3
succeeded to insert 4
succeeded to insert 5
succeeded to insert 6
succeeded to insert 7
succeeded to insert 8
succeeded to insert 9
not able to insert 10
not able to insert 11
not able to insert 12
not able to insert 13
not able to insert 14
items are: [itm 0, itm 1, itm 2, itm 3, itm 4, itm 5, itm 6, itm 7, itm 8, itm 9]
```