# Is there any performance/memory benefit if the capacity of Array List is being specified which is holding only two elements?

Tags: java, collections

I've a Array List which is going to hold only two elements,  I want to specify the initial Capacity to TWO  since initial capacity is ten by default.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<integer>(2);
```

Will I get any performance/memory benefit out of it?

Any discussions around would be appreciated...

Comment: Instead of 10 references you will have 2.

Comment: Why not simple use array? If you are sure that you have fixed size of elements.

Comment: An Array List will match the size of the data that you are storing into it (default starts at 10). By using a normal Array you can specify the size directly so that there are only two spaces for storing your elements.

Comment: The difference between 8 array spots is so small you will not even notice the difference... unless you are on a computer from the 60's maybe.

Comment: If there's a difference, it's miniscule.  The minimum sized allocation for the reference array would be some multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762145/arraylist-resizing should help you out

Comment: If you saved 32 bytes (8 * 4 bytes) you would save 0.00004 cents worth of memory.  You would have to do this A LOT to be worth thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any performance benefit out of it, except for a very small reduction in memory usage.

If you're sure that the size is exactly two elements and it will never change, and to obtain a bit of a performance boost, simply use an array of primitive types (unless there's a really good reason to prefer `Integer`, an `int` is a better option):

```
int[] values = new int[2];
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to store mixed types, then use an `Object[]`. It's still a better alternative than using an `ArrayList`, if the size is fixed to two elements:

```
Object[] values = new Object[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762145/arraylist-resizing). EDIT: <s>Some lists will resize after they are filled past a certain percentage ([load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_factor_%28computer_science%29#Key_statistics)), but this doesn't seem to be the case with ArrayLists.</s>

Sorry for the mistake haha. Got hashtables and dynamic arrays a bit confused.

If you really want to know how ArrayLists work under the hood, check out the [ArrayList source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/4eed3d0d3293/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java). I think the `ensureCapacity()` method that determines whether the backing array needs to be resized:

```
  171     /**
  172      * Increases the capacity of this <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance, if
  173      * necessary, to ensure that it can hold at least the number of elements
  174      * specified by the minimum capacity argument.
  175      *
  176      * @param   minCapacity   the desired minimum capacity
  177      */
  178     public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
  179         modCount++;
  180         int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
  181         if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
  182             Object oldData[] = elementData;
  183             int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
  184             if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
  185                 newCapacity = minCapacity;
  186             // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
  187             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
  188         }
  189     }
```

And the new size happens to be:
      `int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;`

Hope that helps!

Comment: An `ArrayList` doesn't _have_ a load factor, it will only get resized after it's full. If we create a size-2 `ArrayList` it will stay at that size unless further elements are added to it. But if no elements will ever get added, why use an `ArrayList` in the first place?

Comment: Also, the statement "Some lists will resize after they are filled past a certain percentage" is false. The concept of load factor applies to maps and sets, not lists.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! Hashing is different from linear insertion, but I thought that lists might resize before they were full (to save resize time). I suppose that doesn't make much sense though - sorry for the confusion!